# How to deconstruct a LINQ IQueryable / Expression into the constituent parts?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I am writing an extension method which is meant to help prepare a LINQ query before it is actually executed in EF Core.

For example:

```
var context = new SchoolContext();

var studentWithGrade = context.Students
                           .Where(s => s.FirstName == "Bill")
                           .Include(s => s.Grade)
                           .Prepare()
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

I am building the `Prepare()` extension on the `IQueryable<>` interface. In the method, I need to know things about the resulting query to be executed, such as:

- The predicate (`s.FirstName == "Bill"`)
- The selected fields (from the `Students` table, as well as any fields from `s.Grade`)
- The limit (an implied `1` in this case)
- ... and so on.

AFAICT, the `Expression` on the `IQueryable` is transformed into a SQL query (and executed) when `FirstOrDefault()` is called. So this transformation is obviously possible. But I would like to examine the data in a structured way, rather than inspecting a SQL query string. My hope was that I could simply inspect the queryable (`query.Limit < 0`) but the actual storage of these constraints seems buried with reflection in `Expression` object (?) based upon `MethodCallExpression.cs`'s source code.

Comment: This is not easy.  What are you trying to acomplish? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-modify-expression-trees

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I have built an ORM which accepts GraphQL queries. The nature of the GQL AST implies that a naive approach will result in N+1 explosion. The ORM currently works by building a SQL query itself, optimizing the many queries into one via a `Query` class that stores things like `limit`, `offset`, `orderBy`, etc — and then is compiled into SQL (it's pretty much the same thing as IQueryable). However, I am attempting to expose a LINQ interface to the developer — so I need to be able to manipulate that IQueryable object in the same way I do my concrete Query object.

Comment: Concrete example (1) I know that we need to find User ID #1 already (2) I receive a LINQ query to find User ID #2 (`ID == 2`) (3) Because I have determined that the selection sets etc. are the same, I would like to effectively modify the LINQ query I have received to be `ID == 2 OR ID == 1` instead of having two queries that each select a single object. This is what my current `Query` code does using its `limit`, etc. fields to combine queries together and build optimized queries.